# Given 2 int values find which is closer to 15

Tags: java

I am attempting to write a program that takes 2 integer values greater than 0 and print whichever value is closest to 15. And print 0 if they are both over. This is an assumed knowledge question however it has got me very confused for something and my code looks wrong.

I have attempted to try and google similar examples but some don't make sense to me so I just thought it would be better to ask.

```
    public class W221 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            while (JPL.test()) {

  Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
  int num = kb.nextInt();
  int num2 = kb.nextInt();
  int value1;
  int value2;

  if(num <= 15 || num2 <= 15){
    value1 = 15 - num;
    value2 = 15 - num2;

    if(value1>value2){
      if(value1 > 0){
        System.out.println(" " + num2);
      }
    }
    else if(value1<value2){
      if(value2 > 0){
        System.out.println(" " + num);
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    System.out.println(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I AM RE-MAKING THE CODE WITHOUT THE ARRAY, WILL UPDATE CODE SOON.

EDIT 2: I HAVE UPDATED THE CODE PLEASE REFER TO ABOVE

EDIT 3: I have finished removing the array and everything is successful except for when the 'value1 or value2' integers get a negative number. I have looked through the replies but I am confused on how I would change my code to fix this

Comment: That isn't valid Java. You're looking for `else if(condition)`. Something you should do is format your code so it's readable

Comment: Change the "else" to "else if"

Comment: Also why take in an array? If you need two int arguments declare them as the parameters to the method

Comment: @AaronDavis I have removed the array aspect of the code. Hopefully this is the correct way?

Comment: Better now, but you also aren't validating for negative numbers (eg -10 and 3 will return the -10).

Comment: @AaronDavis I have tried to check for negatives by putting 'if(value1>0)' or 'if(value2>0' after each of the 'if(value1>value2)' statements but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try to use `Math.abs()` function to check for closeness to 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally solve this question. It may not be the best way but it works.

```
  public class W221 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  while (JPL.test()) {
  Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
  int num = kb.nextInt();
  int num2 = kb.nextInt();
  int value1;
  int value2;

  if(num <= 15 || num2 <= 15){
    value1 = 15 - num;
    value2 = 15 - num2;

    if(value1 < 0){
      value1 = 50;
    }
    if(value2 < 0){
      value2 = 50;
    }
    if(value1>value2){
        System.out.println(" " + num2);
    }
    else if(value1<value2){
        System.out.println(" " + num);
    }
  }
  else{
    System.out.println(0);
  }}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the code to:

```
if(first>second){
  return num;
}
else if(first<second){
  return num;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It'd be cleaner if you use java's built in Math.max method with a little bit of validation first. For example:

```
private static int maxNonNegativeLessThan15(int a, int b) {
    // Set either or both to 0 in case of negative or >= 15
    if (a >= 15 || a < 0) {
        a = 0;
    }
    if (b >= 15 || b < 0) {
        b = 0;
    }
    return Math.max(a, b);
}
```

Edit: Added code with the input as an example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n1 = in.nextInt();
        int n2 = in.nextInt();
        if (n1 < 0 || n1 >= 15) {
            n1 = 0;
        }
        if (n2 < 0 || n2 >= 15) {
            n2 = 0;
        }
        System.out.println(Math.max(n1,n2));
    }
}
```

Comment: @CandiedOrange I didn't. If the number is negative or greater than or equal to 15 the OP stated it should return 0. The validation checks for negative or >= 15 and sets the argument to 0 in those cases. If both arguments are invalid they are both 0 and 0 is what will be returned. If only 1 argument is invalid then it will be set to 0 and the other one by definition will be greater and be returned. Though I agree that I don't love the name ... but it was named after what the OP was asking for and I hate naming things ;-)

Comment: @CandiedOrange yep, that's a much better name! See, I not only hate naming things, I also suck at it ;-) ... edited the answer to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have not checked the value is less than 0. Hope you can do it by own.

```
import java.util.*;

public class W221 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int firstVal = 0;
        int secondVal = 0;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Give your first value: ");
        firstVal = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("firstVal is: " + firstVal);
        System.out.println("Give your second value: ");
        secondVal = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("secondVal is: " + secondVal);
        System.out.println(checkMe(firstVal, secondVal));
    }

    private static int checkMe(int firstVal, int secondVal) {
        if (Math.max(firstVal, secondVal) > 15) {
            return 0;
        } else
            return Math.max(firstVal, secondVal);
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
Give your first value: 
10
firstVal is: 10
Give your second value: 
11
secondVal is: 11
11
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I am having a little bit of trouble executing this but thank you anyway. I was hoping to primarily stick to the code that I had wrote as this one is fairly confusing. I have updated my code if you wouldn't mind looking.

Comment: @sandalwood please check the updated code with output. Hope it will help

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my initial question.  The purpose of this program is to take two numbers and see which is closer to 15.